# Meteor: onRendered doesn't get fired again after second render iron-route

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have an iron-router route:

```js
    Router.route('/profiel/bewerken', {
        subscriptions: function () {
            return Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
        },
        action: function () {
            if (this.ready())
                this.render('profielBewerken', {
                    to: 'container',
                    data: function () { return Meteor.user(); }
                });
            else 
                this.render('profielBewerken', {
                    to: 'container',
                    data: { loading: true }
                });
        }
    });
```

It waits until the subscription is available, and then renders the template again once the data is available. Even though it does render the template again with the data, my `Template.profielBewerken.onRendered(function () { ...})` callback does not get fired a second time! Does anyone know why not and if there is a solution to this?

I could copy the template and rename it `profielBewerken2` and render that, but then I would have to mirror two chucks of code and manually copy it again every time I modify the template... If there is a better option available then please let me know.

For those interested, I am adding the 'loading' class to a form in the initial template load (see http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html for the effect).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[onRendered only fires when an instance of the template is added to the DOM](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered),  it will thereby not fire again on data changes.

If you want to execute code once the data is ready you should use the [template.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) function like so:

```
Template.profielBewerken.onRendered(function () {
  this.autorun(function (comp) {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
      // do some stuff

      comp.stop();
    }
  });
});
```